# Why is IQueryable lacking all the extension methods that IQueryable<T> has?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iqueryable

Same with `IEnumerable` vs `IEnumerable<T>`. Is it an oversight? Or is there a problem when you don't have the type specified that makes implementing extensions like `.Count()`, `.Where()`, etc impossible?

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx):

> The IQueryable interface is intended for implementation by query providers. It is only supposed to be implemented by providers that **also** implement `IQueryable<T>`. If the provider does not also implement `IQueryable<T>`, the standard query operators cannot be used on the provider's data source.

`IEnumerable` is the artifact of the times when .NET did not have generics ( I don't mean to say it is deprecated, of course ). It has lived on for backward compatibility, after generics and hence `IEnumerable<T>` was introduced. `IQueryable` keeps up with that for consistency. Basically, given that there is generics now, and given the advantages, it makes it useful to implement these extensions only on the generic interfaces. The non-generic ones can always be converted to the generic ones using `Cast<T>`

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not an oversight. Most methods that extend `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` need to know the type of the items. Obviously, methods like `Count()` or `Any()` could have worked on the non-generic interfaces, but it would probably have been confusing. So the only methods that apply to the non-generic interfaces are the one that make them generic (`Cast<T>()` and `OfType<T>()`).

Answer (score 0):

It was probably a deliberate decision rather than an oversight, since an `IEnumerable\IQueryable` can always be converted to an `IEnumerable\IQueryable<object>` using the `Cast` method.

This introduces a small overhead for the caller, but saves implementing many of the extensions twice, e.g. for `Where` you'd need a generic and non-generic version:

```
public static IEnumerable Where(this IEnumerable source, Func<object, bool> predicate) { ... }
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate) { ... }
```

Comment: There would be a benefit - you won't have to call `Cast<T>` first :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - That's a small benefit for the user, but the extra implementation cost doesn't justify such a small overhead.

Comment: What extra implementation cost? It's just a matter of `(this IEnueramble<T> source)` or `(this IEnumerable source)` in method declaration. I'm pretty sure there is another reason why it's done that way.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - You'd have to implement all the `IEnumerable/Queryable` extension methods for the generic and non-generic interfaces, just so a client doesn't need to call `Cast<object>` first.

Comment: No, you wouldn't. Because [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/9eekhta0.aspx) inherits `IEnumerable` methods that do not need direct type knowledge (e.g. `Count()`, `Any()`) could be implemented on `IEnumerable`, and the rest (like `Where(pred)`, `Select(func)`, etc.) on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Possibly for `Count`, but most of the linq extensions could be implemented on `IEnumerable`, and for those you'd have to implement them twice.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - Someone has to implement them, and for them there is a cost in doing so. The question is whether the lack of linq extensions on `IEnumerable` is an oversight. I'm saying it's probably deliberate because there isn't a significant benefit in implementing most of the methods again for the non-generic version of `IEnumerable\IQueryable`.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your answer.